# How to remove Index.php on Select set of URLs Matching Pagination and Component Parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-301

Though index.php is required in every set of url. However, there are 2 sections in which our original url in pagination pages were linked with non index.php

However, due to upgradation of cms, the url set has become with index.php
This only needs to be done on pages having page tag and component only as com_news / com_toyschemes.

Original Correct URL

```
   http://www.abc.com/?page=5&&option=com_latestnews&view=list&Itemid=4
   http://www.abc.com/?page=2&&option=com_toyschemes&view=list&Itemid=3
```

Incorrect URL - which needs to be 301 redirect to Original URL

```
   http://www.abc.com/index.php?page=5&&option=com_latestnews&view=list&Itemid=4
   http://www.abc.com/index.php?page=2&&option=com_toyschemes&view=list&Itemid=3
```

Can someone help on this.

**Edit** - Above url are for illustration. There are 100 of pages with pagination like this in above.

Comment: show your .htaccess ....

Comment: Its the basic htaccess created by joomla. Rewrite needs to be done in above urls. Do you have a solution for this !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this rule to your `.htaccess` that I'm assuming is in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)page=\d+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_(latestnews|toyschemes)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, However, its working only on page no. 2 and 5. They were given for illustratin purpose. There are hundreds of pages in it. How to make it work !!

Comment: @RuchikaModi, just update the rule with `\d+` in place of `[25]` to make it work for all page numbers.